# Add double digits to a countdown timer

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Building a countdown timer for an HTML5 banner project.
Can't figure out how to figure out how to make the days/hours/minutes/seconds be double digit.
07 instead of 7.

```
<script>
const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24,
    countdownDate = "Nov 27, 2020 00:00:00"; // 24hr time

let countDown = new Date(countdownDate).getTime(),
x = setInterval(function() {
    
    //calculate countdown based on current time
    let now = new Date().getTime(),
            distance = countDown - now;
      document.getElementById("days").innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById("hours").innerText =  Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

    //do something later when date is reached
    if (distance < 0) {
        let headline = document.getElementById("headline"),
                countdown = document.getElementById("countdown"),
                content = document.getElementById("content");

        headline.innerText = "Now Open";
        countdown.style.display = "none";
        content.style.display = "block";

        clearInterval(x);
    }

}, second)


</script>
```

Comment: Check out [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: why not check the length of the number and add zero if it is just 1 digit?